# ssh -X does not work on Yosemite

Tags: macos, ssh, x11, xquartz

Can no longer use X11 with ssh. Have XQuartz2.7.7 installed. Logging in with X11 via ssh gives the warnings

> Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
>   Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.

In my own system, `echo $DISPLAY` gives

> /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.GuewxwWwKS/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

However, when I try `xauth  generate $DISPLAY . trusted`, I get the error

> xauth: (argv):1:  bad display name "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.GuewxwWwKS/org.macosforge.xquartz:0" in "add" command

Any ideas in how to fix this?

Comment: The display name as returned by `$DISPLAY` is wrong. It should be something like `:0.0`. Do you set `$DISPLAY` in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` yourself?

Comment: Does it make a difference when you use the `-Y` option instead of `-X`? What operating system is your server using? And: having your `$DISPLAY` set to something in `/tmp/` is perfectly normal on a Mac.

Comment: @jaume I do not set my own $DISPLAY variable. However, manually changing it seems to have fixed it. I'm still now sure how it ended up being what it was.

Comment: Did you restart your Terminal in the meantime? This helped me with weird environment variable problems in the past…

Comment: @Asmus I had previously restarted Terminal as well as rebooting the computer many times to no avail. I've been using OS X 10.10.2. All I did was do something like `DISPLAY=:0.0`, and it worked. I have added this into my .bash_profile

Comment: No, please, do not set `$DISPLAY` manually. Look at what `man ssh` says about X11 forwarding: `The user should not manually set DISPLAY.` This is a potential security risk!

Comment: Then what should I do? It also seems like setting `$DISPLAY` in the bash_profile do not work.The symptom is as follows: ssh with the original `$DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.GuewxwWwKS/org.macosforge.xquartz:0` starts X11, but it gives the error and X11 forwarding does not work. Quit ssh and reset `$DISPLAY` to `:0.0`, retry `ssh -X` and it works

Comment: The warning Asmus mentions above (`The user should not manually set DISPLAY` in `man ssh`) applies to the *computer you connect to*. The reason is that `ssh` will set the DISPLAY variable on the remote computer for you so that X11 traffic goes through the encrypted `ssh` connection. And `man ssh` warns you: Don't modify it! But you must set DISPLAY on your Mac to make it work. Add this line to `~/.bash_profile`: `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, test it and report back.

Comment: So adding that line to `~/.bash_profile` still gives the "setup failed" error. However, as I mentioned above, an interesting thing is that if I just left `DISPLAY` the same, ie. keep it as `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.crAjK9o5ak/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`, do `ssh -X`, quit ssh, then run `export DISPLAY=:0.0` or simply `DISPLAY=:0.0`, X11 works with ssh and I'm able to run GUI applications from the server

Comment: After adding the `export DISPLAY=:0.0` line to `~/.bash_profile` you have to open a new Terminal window for changes to take effect. Alternatively, you need to run `. ~/.bash_profile` in your current shell to source it. Did you do that? If it still doesn't work you can add `alias ssh="DISPLAY=:0.0; ssh"` to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but the results are as described above. It seems like ssh needs the DISPLAY variable to be the original one first when connecting, then changed to the :0.0 value after...

Comment: Have you tried the alias? Do you start XQuartz as a login item?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21049/discussion-between-staksmashr-and-jaume).

Comment: @stakSmashr OK...

Comment: @stakSmashr I've added an answer with a description of the problem, some information on when this bug may be solved  and two workarounds, the one you tested and another one.

Comment: @stakSmashr I finally found some time to install XQuartz and test the second workaround. It works, I added a screenshot. I removed the first workaround, too. You may want to give it a try.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't seem to work for me, I still get the error "$ xterm
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.crAjK9o5ak/org.macosforge.xquartz: unknown host. (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Developer Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia [announced yesterday](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/xquartz-dev/2015-February/003842.html) that this problem is solved in [XQuartz 2.7.8_beta2](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.8_beta2.dmg):

> XQuartz 2.7.8_beta2 is available for download.
>
> You can see http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.8 for a
>   full set of changes, but most noteworth ones are:
>
> 1) xauth now correctly parses the Yosemite launchd $DISPLAY socket path
>   2) libGL has been updated to Mesa 10.4.4
>   3) Various exploits were fixed in xorg-server, freetype, and libpng
>   4) A bug preventing automatic updates in some cases has been fixed

[The bug report](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/2068) is closed and marked as fixed:

> [image]

If you can't (or don't want to) install the beta, you can still use the workaround I explain below.

---

**ANSWER**

**Analysis**

*(scroll down for the workaround section)*

My first thought was "the `DISPLAY` variable is wrong". But it's not.

As it turns out, on OS X 10.10 Yosemite (and [back to 10.8 Mountain Lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4157422?tstart=0)) the `DISPLAY` variable stores a `launchd` socket path:

```
/private/tmp/<socket name>
```

instead of the familiar display name:

```
hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
```

(I've added some information about the `hostname:displaynumber.screennumber` format at the end of this answer.)

This  means that `xauth` has to know how to deal with this special incarnation of the `DISPLAY` variable, and as of Mavericks, it did, but the socket used in Yosemite has a different path (more precisely: `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.XXXX` instead of `/private/tmp/launch-XXXX`), and `xauth` breaks.

This bug was reported to the XQuartz team on Nov 18 2014 (3 months ago) (http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/2068):

> The xauth program has code in both gethost.c and parsedpy.c to look
>   for $DISPLAY names that start with "/tmp/launch", and to treat that as
>   a local socket. However, the location seems to have changed, $DISPLAY
>   now starts with "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd", so the code that is
>   looking for /tmp/launch doesn't catch it. (...)

According to the bug description it is to be solved in XQuartz 2.7.8, which is 4 months late (see the project roadmap page at http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/roadmap).

The patch that fixes the problem was committed on Dec 31 2014 to the freedesktop.org project (http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xauth/commit/parsedpy.c?id=f990dd936b5fd1a40290bb88cde517a0ac38f823):

```
diff --git a/parsedpy.c b/parsedpy.c
index c591b77..7365224 100644
--- a/parsedpy.c
+++ b/parsedpy.c
@@ -42,6 +42,9 @@ in this Software without prior written authorization from The Open Group.
 #include <X11/Xauth.h>         /* for FamilyLocal */
 #include <X11/Xmu/SysUtil.h>

+#include <sys/stat.h>
+#include <sys/syslimits.h>
+
 #if defined(UNIXCONN) || defined(LOCALCONN)
 #define UNIX_CONNECTION "unix"
 #define UNIX_CONNECTION_LENGTH 4
@@ -158,8 +161,32 @@ parse_displayname (const char *displayname,

     if (!host) return False;

-    if(strncmp (host, "/tmp/launch", 11) == 0) {
-        family = FamilyLocal;
+    {
+        /*
+         * If using launchd socket, remove the screen number from the end
+         * of $DISPLAY and check if it is a path to a socket.
+         */
+        char path[PATH_MAX];
+        struct stat sbuf;
(...)
```

So it's only a question of time until this patch finds its way into the next release of XQuartz.

**Workaround**

(tested on OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite.)

Add:

```
alias ssh="ln -fs $(echo $DISPLAY | sed 's:\(/private/tmp/com\.apple\.launchd\.[^/]*\)/.*:\1:') $(echo $DISPLAY | sed 's:/private/tmp/com\.apple\.launchd\.\([^/]*\)/.*:/private/tmp/launch-\1:'); ssh"
```

to `~/.bashrc` and either start a new Terminal window or source it (`. ~/.bashrc`) in your current Terminal session.

This alias first symlinks the socket path to `/private/tmp/launch-XXX` (for example `ln -fs /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.GuewxwWwKS /private/tmp/launch-GuewxwWwKS`) and then starts `ssh`:

[image]

---

For the curious, traditionally, the X server's display name has had this form (from `man X` on Ubuntu):
The X server's display name has this form:

```
hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
```

where:

```
   hostname
           The hostname specifies the name of the machine to which the display  is  physically
           connected.   If  the hostname is not given, the most efficient way of communicating
           to a server on the same machine will be used.

   displaynumber
           The phrase "display" is usually used to refer to  a  collection  of  monitors  that
           share a common set of input devices (keyboard, mouse, tablet, etc.).  Most worksta‐
           tions tend to only have one display.  Larger,  multi-user  systems,  however,  fre‐
           quently  have  several  displays so that more than one person can be doing graphics
           work at once.  To avoid confusion, each display on a machine is assigned a  display
           number (beginning at 0) when the X server for that display is started.  The display
           number must always be given in a display name.

   screennumber
           Some displays share their input devices among two or more monitors.  These  may  be
           configured as a single logical screen, which allows windows to move across screens,
           or as individual screens, each with their own set of windows.  If  configured  such
           that each monitor has its own set of windows, each screen is assigned a screen num‐
           ber (beginning at 0) when the X server for that display is started.  If the  screen
           number is not given, screen 0 will be used.
```